# Use Jinja blocks in Bootstrap tabs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2, extends

I have a main layout.html that has a nav bar that ALL of my pages extend from. I have content in test.html. I want to add bootstrap tabs to test.html (without changing layout.html).

**Plan:**  My plan:
tabs.html extend layout.html
text.html extend tabs.html

**Result:**
Tabs.html inherits the nav bar just fine. But none of the content in text.html shows up. Code is below.

layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
[navbar code]
<div class="container">
    {% block body %}        
    {% endblock body %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In tabs.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

<div id="content">
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#checklist" data-toggle="tab">Checklist</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="checklist">
        {% block overview %}
        {% endblock overview%}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#tabs').tab();
});
</script>    
</div> 
{% endblock body%}
```

In text.html

```
{% extends "tabs.html" %}
{% block overview %}
[content]
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename text.html to _text.html and remove `{% extends "tabs.html"}`.

Next, in tabs.html replace:

```
{% block overview %}
{% endblock %}
```

with:

```
{% include '_text.html' %}
```